# make custom driver auth laravel without model

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, driver

please need help
I try to make auth laravel, but I don't now where I start, but i try to make some code to auth by myself using UserInterface and UserProvider
here are my code :
App\Billing\User.php :

> 

namespace App\Billing;

```
        use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
        use App\Billing\User;

        class AutoLogin implements UserProvider {

             protected $table = 'tblAKSES';
             protected $userInterface;

             public function __construct(){
                $this->userInterface = new App\Billing\User();
             }

             public function retrieveById($identifier) {

                  $this->userInterface->setUsername($identifier);

                   $user = DB::table($this->table)->where('USERNAME', $this->userInterface->getUsername())->first();
    if (!is_null($user)){
        return $this->userInterface->getUsername();
     }
        return null;

    }

public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token){

    $this->userInterface->setUsername($identifier);
    $this->userInterfacesetRememberToken($token);

    $data = array(
            'ID' => $this->userInterface->getAuthIdentifier(),
            'remember_token' => $this->userInterface->getRememberToken(), 
    );

    $user = DB::table($this->table)->where($data)->first();
    if (is_null($user)){
        return $this->userInterface->getUsername();
    }
    return null;

}

              public function retrieveByCredentials ($credential){
             $user =     DB::table($this->table)->where($credential['USERNAME'])->first();
     if (Hash::check($user->PASSWORD, Hash::make($credential['PASSWORD']))     && !is_null($user)) {
         return $this->userInterface->getAuthIdentifier();
      }
      return null;
   }
```

public function validateCredentials(User $username, $credential){

```
    $this->userInterface->setUsername($credential['USERNAME']);
    $this->userInterface->setPassword($credential['PASSWORD']);

    $user = DB::table($this->table)->where('USERNAME', $username->getAuthIdentifier())->first();
    if (is_null($user)){
        return false;
    }

    if(Hash::check($user->PASSWORD, $username->getAuthPassword())){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function updateRememberToken(User $username, $token){
    $this->userInterface->setRememberToken($token);
    DB::table($this->table)->where('USERNAME', $username->getAuthIdentifier())->update([
            $username->getRememberTokenName => $username->getRememberToken,
    ]);
}
```

}

here my class using Autheticable:

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
namespace App\Billing;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class User implements Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'tblAKSES';
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $token;

    public function getToken(){
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function setUsername($username){
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function setPassword($password){
        $pass = $this->password = $password;
        return $pass;
    }

    public function setToken($token){
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->USERNAME;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword(){
            return $this->PASSWORD;
    }

    public function getRememberToken(){
            return $this->token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($token){
        return $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return remember_token;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifierName(){
        $user = DB::table($this->table)->where([
                'USERNAME' => $this->getUsername(),
        ])->first();
        if (!is_null($user)) {
            return $user->USERNAME;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: What is not working? How do you expect it to work?

Comment: yes, I try to make by myself it flow instrutions laravel